# On the change in half-life of tritium traveling at near $c$ in a cyclotron

Tags: spacetime, mass-energy, time-dilation, particle-accelerators

Barring physical effects I do not know about, I would expect that the beta decay of tritium of about 12.32 years to increase by the time dilatation accorded to its increased mass while traveling in a cyclotron.

Now I am a bit confused by the inertial versus non-inertial conditions for Lorentz transformations, so I would appreciate a transformation formula for the increase of half-life in a cyclotron. Also, the energy of decay, I would expect to increases with the relative kinetic versus rest mass ratio. Does it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_dilation#Clock_hypothesis

Comment: @G.Smith Yes, thanks, that is my conjecture. I'll answer my own question if no one else does. The point of asking is that many people say "nothing affects radioactive decay rate" without due consideration.